# Does this anime quirk have a name?

Tags: anime-production, tropes

I've always liked this quirky anime technique, which was used in several anime around the 1990s and 2000s, but not THAT often. What is it called and how does it work?

How do you animate it and when does it get used?

[image: magic knight rayearth - chibi]

I also found other examples

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the [Chibi](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=chibi) style of drawing the characters smaller, or to the short clips which usually feature this style? The clips generally come during the middle (before and after ad breaks) or "In the next episode" segments of an episode.

Comment: @TheGamer007 as his title mentions "run" I assume he is talking about the feet turning into what seems like cloudy circles instead

Comment: @Dimitrimx ah, I completely misinterpreted that. Thanks.

Comment: is there a name for it?

Comment: you might want to also add what do you mean by "how does it work?" you mean how does it work being animated or how does the run work in real life?

Answer (score 5):

It's most likely a mix of,

- [Human Hummingbird](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanHummingbird)
- [Kewpie Doll Surprise](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KewpieDollSurprise)
- [Wheel o' Feet](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WheelOFeet)
- [Floating Limbs](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FloatingLimbs)
- Possibly also [Thundering Herd](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThunderingHerd) if you want to consider the background or context for the first image

Comment: Is there any more info

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is an actual name for this but it's likely a trope that derived from older manga works., most notably that of Fujio Akatsuka. It's best described as an "afterimage" of movement.

[image: afterimages of Fujio Akatsuka 1]

[image: afterimages of Fujio Akatsuka 2]

There are many names for such, like "ghost feet", but there's not any real agree upon terms for this trope.

[image: ghost feet]

- From [this book about super-deformed characters](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8D%E6%96%B9-%E2%80%95%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A1%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E3%82%92%E5%BE%B9%E5%BA%95%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC-%E8%B6%85%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA-%E6%BF%B1%E5%85%83-%E9%9A%86%E8%BC%94/dp/476830723X/)

Comment: WOW. Is that page online

Comment: What page are you referring to?

Comment: The one about that super-deformed run, can I find it anywhere?

Comment: To download, not really.

Comment: That's ok, I'll set up another bounty

Comment: I can't set up another bounty

Comment: Please use our [meta site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/) for such questions in the future. The faq on the main meta site covers your question on a second bounty https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: I'll need 16 upvotes to get a better answer, but thank you for yours